# When using GraphQL/Apollo Server, should an error be thrown for no database results?

Tags: arrays, graphql, apollo-server

If a resolver gets a user from a database for example and no user was not found, should an error be thrown? What is best practice for no data found?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a case to be made for simply returning `null`, rather than throwing an error, particularly in this scenario. The `errors` part of your response will includes two general types of errors:

- Execution errors that result from some thrown error or rejected Promise encountered during execution
- Response validation errors that result from the response not conforming to the schema

In both of these cases, something **bad** and **unexpected** happened server-side. As a client, I need to maybe file a defect, open an issue or go yell at somebody 3 cubicles over. But the point is, these errors shouldn't occur in the normal course of things.

On the other hand, let's consider looking up a user by their username or some other identifier. Rather than a search that returns an array of users, let's assume we're using an exact match and only returning a single user.

```
type Query {
  user(username: String!): User
}
```

In a scenario like this, not finding a matching user in the database some of the time is probably expected. As long as the field is nullable, the client will know to expect either a User or null, and can handle either scenario just fine.

If we throw an error, the field will still return null, but now we'll also see an error in our `errors` array. The client will now have to do additional work to determine if the error occurred because there was no user found, or if something else went wrong (after all, if a server error occurred, we may need to take additional action, for example alerting the user to the fact). Moreover, our `errors` array is no longer an indicator of response "health", since it may include errors that are being thrown as part of our regular business logic.

Comment: That's a very interesting take, Daniel. So if there are business logic errors, should they be moved to the response itself - for example creating a `UserResponse` type that would have a nullable `user: User` field and a nullable `error` field of type `String` or `[String!]` or `Error`? So as to keep business logic errors separate from 'pure' GraphQL errors?

Comment: The use cases I have in mind are varied: an invalid auth token, a malformed auth header, a user without the role/permissions to execute a query/mutation, etc.

Comment: All those scenarios are ones I wouldn't expect to encounter during normal use of the API. If you're processing some query, attempt to get the user from the JWT token and determine that user doesn't exist in the database, by all means throw an error. I don't know if I would go as far as to wrap all my Query type fields with some kind of `Response` type.

Comment: On the other hand, this is a common pattern for mutations. For example, take a look at how [Shopify does things](https://help.shopify.com/en/api/graphql-admin-api/reference/mutation/collectioncreate).

Comment: Thank you, very interesting to see the varied approaches to handling business logic errors.

Comment: @DanielRearden Thank you for the response. This discussion is literally about what we are facing with our current API. We have been using Mutation Response Types for some time now. We also started using Query Response Types to standardize the flow of data. For the past month we have been migrating one of the APIs to throwing errors, using Apollo Error objects and the whole thing has gotten messy and difficult to reason about. Allot of sleep has been lost on should we remove the Query Response Types or leave them be.

Comment: I've actually started a post on this topic as I cannot find any real discussions on it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54657425/what-are-the-downside-to-having-query-response-types-in-graphql

Answer (score 0):

I would say that's really up to you and the schema you've defined.

If you have a schema like

```
type Query {
  # allow null to be returned
  user(where: FindUserInput): User
}
```

then you could return null when no user is found.

If your schema doesn't allow returning `null`, like

```
type Query {
  # only allowed to return a valid User object
  user(where: FindUserInput): User!
}
```

then throwing an error is the way to go.

I don't believe there is an absolute best practice, it's more about what behavior you're looking for in your project.

Comment: If you know you're going to occasionally throw an error for the `user` field here, it would actually be better to make the field nullable. Because of the way GraphQL handles errors and nullability, a non-null will cause your entire `data` property to return null. Making `user` nullable means you can request other queries and still get a partial response for *those* fields, along with your error.

Comment: By that reasoning, shouldn't all root queries allow for null to be returned, so as to allow for partial responses? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Not necessarily. Let's assume our entire endpoint is gated in such a way that I can't access it unless I'm logged in. Now let's say I have a `viewer` field that returns the currently logged in User, and maybe a `config` field that returns some info. Here, `viewer` should always exist and I can make it non-null. If something goes terribly wrong and we return null, fine, blow up the whole query.

Comment: On the other hand, imagine we don't gate the endpoint and want to be able to request the `viewer` field as a way to check if we're currently logged in. As a client, I want to be able to request both fields to render my home page appropriately. Making `viewer` non-null will force me to either fetch `config` separately or implement some kind of retry logic.

Comment: Mind you, this concern applies to all fields, not just root-level ones. A non-null field that throws because it resolves to null will "bubble up" all the way to the first available nullable parent.

Comment: The point is: if business rules dictate that a field could end up null (whether because the data doesn't exist or because we're **choosing** to throw some kind of error in some scenario), that field shouldn't be marked as non-null.

Comment: @DanielRearden Got it. Thank you for these very detailed explanations, Daniel, very enlightening!