# What are the downside to having Query Response Types in GraphQL?

Tags: javascript, graphql, apollo-server

In the Apollo documentation it talks about using Mutation Response Types where you would return a response that included keys for `code`, `success`, `message`, as well as keys for the specific data that was change. i.e. a user.

**EXAMPLE**:

```
interface MutationResponse {
  code: String!
  success: Boolean!
  message: String!
}
type UpdateUserMutationResponse implements MutationResponse {
  code: String!
  success: Boolean!
  message: String!
  user: User
}
```

We have been using this approach for some time now. We also adopted this approach for our queries and have a Query Response Type for each query.

If a user cannot be found for example, the response returns the appropriate details to the client.

Throwing errors from our microservices down the pipe to the client makes things allot more messy and difficult to reason about. We have started reworking one of our APIs to not use Query Response Types and dealing with errors, etc. has become way more complex.

So my question is, what would be the downsides of using a Query Response Type, in addition to Mutation Response Types? We can't decide if we should replace the Query Response Types or leave them be.

Comment: A good starting point would be looking at each error you're anticipating and asking whether the client cares about the nature of the error. If you're validating query input further upstream, it totally makes sense to send very specific errors back to the client. For example, a database needs a value to be formatted as a UUID, but the string the client sent was not -- as a client, I want to know what field threw and why.

Comment: On the other hand, if we fail to connect to a microservice or we hit some unexpected error during execution, as a client I don't really care. There was an internal server error, maybe I back off and try again or I prompt the user to do so. In my opinion, it's sufficient to have an error inside your `errors` array in these cases. If you have a lot of the former, it probably makes sense to use a response wrapper type. On the other hand, if you only have a handful, you might even get away with validating through GraphQL using customer scalars.

Comment: It's a good question, but it's really dependent on the needs of the clients actually consuming the API, as well as the types of errors you're dealing with or at least anticipating. Outside of errors that involve invalid inputs, are there any others that your team feels should be exposed to the client?

Comment: @DanielRearden Errors such as a microservice being unreachable or an internal error such as a database being offline, are not returned in the Query Response Type. An Internal Server Error is returned in the errors array. The only errors/messages that we return in our Query Type are data that the client cares about. For example, in my previous question, if a query requested a User for and that user was not found, not available to the requesting user (blocked), etc. the query would return with a status as false, along with details as to why, so that the client could take the appropriate actions.

Comment: We have both a web app which is public facing and an internal management system that is private. Both GraphQL gateways use response types for mutations as well as queries. It would be considerable work to transition both to using the errors array for errors such as missing or invalid form, as well as actual errors like you talk about that the client doesn't care about.

Comment: Currently, a microservice does its work, returns a Query or Mutation Response Type  to the GraphQL gateway, which gets checked against the type schema, then that gets passed onto the client. In the throw version, the microservice throws, which gets caught by the gateway, which then has to throw again using an Apollo error to the client. Anyways, @DanielRearden thanks for the feedback and I hope this makes sense.